# REST API design: the endpoint which returns a report

Tags: api, rest

I need to create an endpoint which return some form of a report. Something like:
`api-v1/report?format=XML`. And it report with custom XML-report.
What should I do in case xsl?
`api-v1/report?format=XSL` is it normal to answer on such request with XSL(Excel) file?

Comment: Can we assume you mean `xls` (=Excel)? Anyway, the desired format is supposed to be defined in the `Accept` header. That's what it's for.

Comment: @zeroflagL you should put this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

the resource (data) should be independent from the formatting/encoding
whether it is xml, json, xls, csv, etc should be determined through "content negotiation" usually accomplished by using the "accept" header.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to respond with the URL of where the file can be downloaded from, instead of sending the contents of the file.